# Why am I getting a NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm extending the `ApplicationUser` class with some extra information and relationships that I need to use in my application.

Here's my `ApplicationUser` class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return FirstName + " " + LastName;
        }
    }

    [Display(Name = "Job Title")]
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("FullName", this.FullName));

        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

My `Permission` model:

```
public class Permission : BaseEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Many to One
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

And my `Create()` method in my `UsersController`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(CreateUserViewModel model)
{
    var selectedPermissions = model.Permissions.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.ID).ToList();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser {
            UserName = model.Email,
            Email = model.Email,
            PrivateEmail = model.PrivateEmail,
            FirstName = model.FirstName,
            LastName = model.LastName,
            JobTitle = model.JobTitle
        };


        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            // Remove all existing Roles
            var userRoles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);
            var uRoles = String.Join(", ", userRoles.ToArray());
            await UserManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user.Id, uRoles);

            // Add selected Role
            await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.Role);

            foreach (var permissionID in selectedPermissions)
            {
                var permission = await db.Permissions.FindAsync(permissionID);
                if (permission != null)
                {
                    user.Permissions.Add(permission);
                }
            }
            await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Default");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    var allPermissions = await db.Permissions.ToListAsync(); // returns List<Permission>
    var checkBoxListItems = new List<CheckBoxListItem>();
    foreach (var permission in allPermissions)
    {
        checkBoxListItems.Add(new CheckBoxListItem()
        {
            ID = permission.ID,
            Display = permission.Name,
            IsChecked = selectedPermissions.Contains(permission.ID)
        });
    }
    model.Permissions = checkBoxListItems;
    PopulateRolesDropDownList(model.Role);
    return View(model);
```

}

So on posting the form to create a new user, the user is saved to the database and the selected role is also saved. But when it gets to the line  `user.Permissions.Add(permission);` it fails with the error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I've added breakpoints and can see that neither `user` or `permission` is null when it gets to the failing line.

It would be much appreciated is someone can any tell me why I'm getting this error?

Comment: 99% - Permissions is null. You need to create an object of this list.

Comment: probably user.Permissions not initialized

Comment: In the ApplicationUser constructor: Permissions = new List<UserPermission>(). You're trying to add to list that does not exists

Comment: is user.Permissions null? Try adding an if(user.Permissions == null) user.Permissions = new <whateverIntellisenseSuggests>() before adding the item

Comment: Thanks all you are all right, basic stuff I guess but I'm new to asp.net so still learning. @CallumBradbury yours was the most helpful comment, post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like user.Permissions is null.

*Edit: Rephrased as answer, not question. :-)*

Comment: Is it a question or an answer ? :) You're right anyway